# How to remove all non-alphanumeric characters from a string expect decimal point in Java

Tags: java, regex, decimal

Having this String with decimal point, I would like to remove all non alphaNumeric expect the decimal point.

```
 String toPharse = "the. book - cost 7.55 dollars.";

 String newPharse =  toPharse.replaceAll("[^A-Za-zd.0-9 ]", " ").replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

Currently I get `"the. book cost 7.55 dollars."`;

However I would like to return `"the book cost 7.55 dollars"`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```bash
String toPharse = "the. book - cost 7.55 dollars.";
toPhrase = toPharse
   .replaceAll("(?<!\\d)\\.(?!\\d)|[^a-zA-Z\\d. ]+", "")
   .replaceAll("\\h{2,}", " ");

//=> "the book cost 7.55 dollars"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jXnnPM/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!\\d)`: Previous character is not a digit
- `\\.`: Match a dot
- `(?!\\d)`: Next character is not a digit
- `|`: OR
- `[^a-zA-Z\\d. ]+`: Match 1+ of non-alphanumeric characters that are not space or dot
- `.replaceAll("\\h{2,}", " ")`: is for replacing 2+ whitespaces with a single space